# Shortcut to Show Context Actions in WebStorm not working

Tags: webstorm

As of the last few...months or something (who knows anymore these days) -- probably since the 2021 update, the shortcut for "Show Context Actions" doesn't actually bring up the menu. I've got it as <kbd>cmd + .</kbd> (the default, I believe, at least for my VSCode keymap).

The light bulb comes up after a quick hover, and I can click on that or of course right-click the editor. But I used to be able to just bring up that menu with the shortcut.

Help?

Comment: Go to Keymap in your Settings/Preferences and use "Find Action by Shortcut" button -- there press your shortcut and see what action(s) have it assigned. Maybe it's not assigned any more / was reset somehow?

Comment: Nope it's assigned to the same thing, as I mentioned. Strangely I noticed it's also assigned to opt+enter, and that does work.

Comment: Maybe the same shortcut is also assigned to another action .. that may have a priority? If that's so -- try removing that shortcut from other actions. No better ideas from me (+ not a Mac user to test it myself)

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by going to `file` -> `Invalidate Caches...`

Requires restart & re-index which can take a few seconds.

Alternatively, the "`Problems`" tool window at bottom/side of screen often shows the context action too.